# how modify script to do GUI

Tags: python

I'm learning to script in Blender, and I'm writing script to do trees using L-systems with the GUI. My question is where do I start to draw GUI? where in the  code? All from Tree Characteristics I want to put in the GUI.

```
import math
import random
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
### Configuration Options ##
# Tree Characteristics
ANGLE = 45                      # Angle which new branches come off of (in degrees)
BRANCH_LENGTH = 10              # Length of parent branch
BRANCH_DIVISOR = 1.6            # How much to divide parent branch length by
THICKNESS = 0.25                # How thick the branches should be
DEPTH = 5                       # How many levels to render
SOFT_ENDS = True                # Add soft ends (spheres) to the branches
# Twist at the A grammar
TWIST = False                   # Twist the child branches around the parent branch
TWIST_AMOUNT = 45               # How much to twist by
# Mesh Resolution
VERTICES = 16                   # For branches (cylinders)
RING_COUNT = 16                 # For soft ends (spheres)
SEGMENTS = 16                   # For soft ends (spheres)
# Apply some randomness to the tree
VARIATION_MODE = False          # apply a random variation to the tree, gives it a more natural feel
BRANCH_LENGTH_VARIATION = .5    # How much to vary the branch length
TWIST_VARIATION = 15            # How much to vary the twist by
ANGLE_VARIATION = 30            # How much to vary the child branche's branch angle by
#random.seed(0)                 # use this to set a random seed
# class for storing render state
class RenderParams:
    __slots__ = (
        'max_depth',
        'cur_depth',
        'branch_length',
        'matrix_chain',
    )
    # sets up the Rendering Parameters
    def __init__(self, branch_length=10, max_depth=5):
        self.max_depth = max_depth
        self.cur_depth = 0
        self.branch_length = branch_length
        self.matrix_chain = [Matrix.Identity(4)]
    # Checks if we are deeper than our current depth or not
    def depthGood(self):
        return self.cur_depth < self.max_depth

    # Multiplies the stored matrx_chain
    def computedMatrixChain(self):
        m = self.matrix_chain[0]

        for i in range(1, len(self.matrix_chain)):
            m *= self.matrix_chain[i]

        return m
# This is used so that we don't accidentally add more sphere than we need to
_soft_ends_set = set()
# Makes a branch
#   branch_length -- a non-negative number, how long each branch should be
#   world_matrix -- A Matrix that will be where the placement of the branch starts
def mkBranch(branch_length, world_matrix):
    global _soft_ends_set
    # For the endpoints
    if SOFT_ENDS:
        # compute locations
        a = world_matrix
        b = world_matrix * Matrix.Translation((0, 0, branch_length))
        # Get their tranlations (fronzen) (so we don't double add them)
        a_loc = a.to_translation().freeze()
        b_loc = b.to_translation().freeze()
        # first endpoint
        if a_loc not in _soft_ends_set:
            _soft_ends_set.add(a_loc)
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments=SEGMENTS, ring_count=RING_COUNT, size=THICKNESS)
            bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world *= a
        # second
        if b_loc not in _soft_ends_set:
            _soft_ends_set.add(b_loc)
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments=SEGMENTS, ring_count=RING_COUNT, size=THICKNESS)
            bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world *= b
    # The actual branch
    mid = world_matrix * Matrix.Translation((0, 0, branch_length / 2))
    cylinder = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
        vertices=VERTICES,
        radius=THICKNESS,
        depth=branch_length,
    )
    bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world *= mid
# Grammar
# A -> BCDE
# B -> A
# C -> A
# D -> A
# E -> A
# (All these are in the context of having a max render depth
# A = Go forward x units, perform B & C,  then back x units
# B = Turn left 45 degrees, perform A, then turn right 45 degrees
# C = Turn right 45 degrees, perform A, then turn left 45 degrees
# A - BCDE
def A(rp):
    # Check depth
    if not rp.depthGood():
        return
    # Record the amounts
    original_branch_length = rp.branch_length
    branch_length = rp.branch_length
    twist_amount = TWIST_AMOUNT
    # If variations are on, apply some
    if VARIATION_MODE:
        branch_length += random.uniform(-BRANCH_LENGTH_VARIATION, BRANCH_LENGTH_VARIATION)
        twist_amount += random.uniform(-TWIST_VARIATION, TWIST_VARIATION)
    # Make the branch
    mkBranch(branch_length, rp.computedMatrixChain())
    # Increase distance & twist
    rp.matrix_chain.append(Matrix.Translation((0, 0, branch_length)))
    if TWIST:
        rp.matrix_chain.append(Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(twist_amount), 4, 'Z'))
    rp.branch_length = branch_length / BRANCH_DIVISOR
    # Do the other grammars
    rp.cur_depth += 1
    B(rp)
    C(rp)
    D(rp)
    E(rp)
    rp.cur_depth -= 1
    # undo distance increase and twist
    rp.branch_length = original_branch_length
    if TWIST:
        rp.matrix_chain.pop()
    rp.matrix_chain.pop()
# B -> A
def B(rp):
    # Check depth
    if not rp.depthGood():
        return

    # Set the angle
    angle = ANGLE
    if VARIATION_MODE:
        angle += random.uniform(-ANGLE_VARIATION, ANGLE_VARIATION)
    # Rotate & go deeper
    rp.matrix_chain.append(Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(angle), 4, 'X'))
    A(rp)
    rp.matrix_chain.pop()
# C -> A
def C(rp):
    # Check depth
    if not rp.depthGood():
        return

    # Set the angle
    angle = ANGLE
    if VARIATION_MODE:
        angle += random.uniform(-ANGLE_VARIATION, ANGLE_VARIATION)
    # Rotate & go deeper
    rp.matrix_chain.append(Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(angle), 4, 'Y'))
    A(rp)
    rp.matrix_chain.pop()
# D -> A
def D(rp):
    # check depth
    if not rp.depthGood():
        return

    # Set the angle
    angle = ANGLE
    if VARIATION_MODE:
        angle += random.uniform(-ANGLE_VARIATION, ANGLE_VARIATION)
    # Rotate & go deeper
    rp.matrix_chain.append(Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(-angle), 4, 'X'))
    A(rp)
    rp.matrix_chain.pop()
# E -> A
def E(rp):
    # check depth
    if not rp.depthGood():
        return

    # Set the angle
    angle = ANGLE
    if VARIATION_MODE:
        angle += random.uniform(-ANGLE_VARIATION, ANGLE_VARIATION)
    # Rotate & go deeper
    rp.matrix_chain.append(Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(-angle), 4, 'Y'))
    A(rp)
    rp.matrix_chain.pop()
# render something
rp = RenderParams(BRANCH_LENGTH, DEPTH)
A(rp)
```

Here is my code.

```
import bpy
import math
import random
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from bpy.props import *



bl_info = {
    "name": "Extra Objects",
    "version": (0, 3, 0),
    "blender": (2, 74, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh",
    "description": "Generate tree",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}

def make_params(self, depth):

    __slots__ = (
        'max_depth',
        'current_depth',
        'branch_length',
        'matrix_chain',
    )

    self.max_depth = depth
    self.current_depth = 0
    self.branch_length = 10
    self.matrix_chain = [Matrix.Identity(4)]

    #check_depth(self, self.current_depth, self.max_depth)
    #calculate_matrix(self)

    #chyba zbedne bo mamy okreslonej dlugosci lancuch znakowy
    """def check_depth(self, current_depth, max_depth):
    return self.current_depth < self.max_depth  """

def calculate_matrix(self):
        m = self.matrix_chain[0]

        for i in range(1, len(self.matrix_chain)):
            m *= self.matrix_chain[i]

        return m

def make_branch(lenght, thickness, matrix):
    middle = matrix * Matrix.Translation((0, 0, lenght /2 ))
    cylinder = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
        vertices = 8,
        radius= thickness,
        depth=lenght)
    bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world *= middle


def make_tree(self, formula, depth):

    roz_A = 'BCDE'
    roz_B = 'A'
    roz_C = 'A'
    roz_D = 'A' 
    roz_E = 'A'
    nowa = ""

    k=0
    c=0
    while k < depth:
        for i, c in enumerate(formula):
            if c == "A":
                nowa = nowa + roz_A
            elif c == "B":
                nowa = nowa + roz_B
            elif c == "C":
                nowa = nowa + roz_C
            elif c == "D":
                nowa = nowa + roz_D
            elif c == "E":
                nowa = nowa + roz_E
        k=k+1
        formula = formula + nowa
        #print(nowa)
        #print(k)

    #print(nowa)"""

    render = make_params(self, self.branch_depth)

    for i, c in enumerate(formula):
        if c == "A":
            A(self, render)
        elif c == "B":
            B(self, render)
        elif c == "C":
            C(self, render)
        elif c == "D":
            D(self, render)
        elif c == "E":
            E(self, render)


def A(self, render):
    original_lng = self.branch_length
    branch_lng = self.branch_length
    twist_amount = self.twist_variation

    if self.variation_mode:
        branch_lng += random.uniform(-self.branch_variation, self.branch_variation)
        twist_amount += random.uniform(-self.twist_variation, self.twist_variation)

    M = calculate_matrix(self)
    make_branch(branch_lng, self.thickness, calculate_matrix(self))
    trans = Matrix.Translation((0, 0, branch_lng))
    M.matrix_chain.append(trans)
    return

def B(self, render):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=4, radius1=1, radius2=0, depth=2, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 2.5))

    return

def C(self, render):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=5, radius1=1, radius2=0, depth=3, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 2.5))

    return

def D(self, render):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=6, radius1=1, radius2=0, depth=4, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 2.5))

    return

def E(self, render):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=8, radius1=1, radius2=0, depth=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 2.5))

    return


class TreesGenerator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Trees Generator"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.tree_add"
    bl_label = "Trees Generator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'

    """__slots__ = (
        'max_depth',
        'current_depth',
        'branch_length',
        'matrix',
    )"""

    grammar = ['A', 'AB', 'ABB', 'BA', 'BBA']
    random_value=[]
    random.seed(0)

    for i in range(10):
        random_value.append(random.random())

    #if random_value[1] != 0:
    #   bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))


    def InitialProperties(X, Y):
        return IntProperty(
            name = "Integer",
            description = "Int",
            default = X,
            min = X,
            max = Y)
        #wartosci domyslne w panelu

    def InitialPropertiesFl(X, Y):
        return FloatProperty(
            name = "Float",
            description = "Float",
            default = X,
            min = X,
            max = Y)

    def InitialPropertiesBl():
        return BoolProperty(
            name = "Randomness",
            default = False)

        ### PIEŃ
    trunk = InitialProperties(0, 4) # tu bedzie tablica z formula poczatkowa


        ### GAŁĘZIE
    branch_depth = InitialProperties(1, 5) # maksymalne rozwiniecie stringa
    branch_length = InitialPropertiesFl(1, 2) #wspolczynnik dlugosci galezi, im wiekszy wspolczynnik tym krotsze galezie
    seeds = InitialProperties(0, 10) # 10 roznych stringow, wybor z tablicy do ktorej wpisze randomy
    twist = InitialProperties(10, 16)
    thickness = InitialPropertiesFl(0.01, 0.3)

        ### RANDOMY
    variation_mode = InitialPropertiesBl()
    branch_variation = InitialPropertiesFl(0, 1)
    twist_variation = InitialProperties(10, 170)
    angle_variation = InitialProperties(10, 170)


        ### PANEL
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout


            ### PIEŃ
        layout.label("Trunk")
        row = layout.row()
        box = row.box()
        split = box.split(percentage=0.35)
        col = split.column()
        col.label("Grammar:")
        #layout.separator()
        split = split.split(percentage=0.9)
        col = split.column()
        col.prop(self, 'trunk')
        layout.separator()


            ### GAŁĘZIE
        layout.label("Branches")
        row = layout.row()
        box = row.box()
        split = box.split(percentage=0.35)
        col = split.column()
        col.label("Depth:")
        col.label("Thickness:")
        col.label("Branch divisor:")
        col.label("Seeds:")
        col.label("Twist:")
        #layout.separator()
        split = split.split(percentage=0.9)
        col = split.column()
        col.prop(self, 'branch_depth')
        col.prop(self, 'thickness')
        col.prop(self, 'branch_length')
        col.prop(self, 'seeds')
        col.prop(self, 'twist')
        layout.separator()


            ### RANDOMY
        #layout.label("dupa")
        layout.prop(self, "variation_mode")
        if self.variation_mode == True:
            row = layout.row()
            box = row.box()
            split = box.split(percentage=0.45)
            col = split.column()
            col.label("Branch lenght variation:")
            col.label("Twist variation:")
            col.label("Angle variation:")
            split = split.split(percentage=0.9)
            col = split.column()
            col.prop(self, 'branch_variation')
            col.prop(self, 'twist_variation')
            col.prop(self, 'angle_variation')
            layout.separator()
        else:
            layout.separator()





    def execute(self, context):

        formula = self.grammar[self.trunk]
        #make_params(self, self.branch_depth)
        make_tree(self, formula, self.branch_depth)
        return{'FINISHED'}





def add_object_button(self, context):
    """adds button"""
    self.layout.operator(
        TreesGenButton.bl_idname,
        text=TreesGenButton.__doc__,
        icon='PLUGIN')


def register():
    """register"""
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)
def unregister():
    """unregister"""    
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

It's not finished yet, so it looks chaotic, because all the time I have this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Matrix' obcject has no attribute 'matrix_chain'
```

I'm noob in programming so I think that's a stupid error but I don't know how to fix it. I'm very grateful to any help.

Comment: I've tried your scripts, the first one builds the tree and the second one runs without errors. Could you please explain the problem you are facing?

Comment: sure. it runs without error but when you do 'Space' and in this menu you put name of program Trees Generator then you will see error AttributeError: 'Matrix' obcject has no attribute 'matrix_chain'. and i don't know what is wrong with matrix. i'm not sure but i guess that is problem with inheritance.

Comment: Looks like it should be `self.matrix_chain.append(trans)` on line 117.  `self` the operator has a "matrix_change" attribute.  `M` is a matrix and doesn't.

Comment: I do second class instead of def make_prams and works, so problem is solved :)